# iOS apps listening to shared storage on background

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I want to use app groups to share data between two apps. I want to use both NSUserDefaults and may be NSFileCoordinator for file storage.

Now I want app A to write to shared storage and then app B to listen using NSFilepresenter. Can App B in background listen to changes and trigger some tasks in background ?

So generic question is , can apps listen to shared storages while in background and react while being in background ?

Best Regards,
Saurav

Comment: How large are these files @saurav? You might consider using Core Data. You may want to check this link out :https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Comment: @MihirThanekar thanks for reply...my data will be not much...may be a file with 50KB of data...my main concern is can i run a listener from an application on the change of data storage (if through core data)  and trigger the application running in background to run some operations ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to do something if a local state changes (in the background), you may consider using background fetch.

That way you can update your operations in the background and check if the storage changed in the execution block.

See the links for more info:

- [Background execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)
- [Background modes Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: Thanks Mihir for the reply...so with background fetch...my application B will wake up from time to time and then check if there is any change in the storage and then react accordingly ?..if the operation falls under ios's predefined background tasks...it can continue to run in background

Comment: Precisely. You can configure it to that.